# WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server

Tags: permissions, wamp

I am new to [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) and I have just installed it today.

The setup went well and localhost seems to work, but when I try to access [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) I get this error:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

Why do I get this permission access error with phpMyAdmin?

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Be carefull with the accepted answer, WAMP's phpmyadmin is configured to allow root with no password by default. `Allow from all` would open the database to the public. The real problem is that WAMP is binding to an IPv6 address on your version of Windows. To fix just add `Allow from ::1` in `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` `<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">`.

Comment: Strangely, this same question, give or take, is a [protected as a community wiki here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600795/wamp-server-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on)

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Change the file content of `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` to the following.

Note: You should set the `Allow` Directive to allow from your local machine for security purposes. The directive `Allow from all` is insecure and should be limited to your local machine.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here my WAMP installation is in the `c:\wamp` folder. Change it according to your installation.

Previously, it was like this:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Modern versions of Apache 2.2 and up will look for a IPv6 loopback instead of a IPv4 loopback (your localhost).

> The real problem is that wamp is binding to an IPv6 address. The fix:
>   just add `Allow from ::1` - Tiberiu-Ionuț Stan

```
<Directory "c:/wamp22/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Directory>
```

This will allow only the local machine to access local apps for Apache.

Restart your Apache server after making these changes.

Comment: Previously this will be 
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

Also restart your apache server service after modifying

Comment: depends on your apache version. apache > 2.4.x, you need a different config.  see my answer below

Comment: It seems like the reason why by default this was set to 127.0.0.1 is because that is the localhost ipv4 address. For some reason even though you are on the localhost, phpmyadmin is not allowing you in. Then you allow any user to gain access. This doesn't seem like a security vulnerability unless you put your wamp site online. I may be wrong though -- complete novice. Actually yeah, read the rest of the thread. Don't do the above fix.

Comment: Not that its a big deal, but you can just remove "Deny from all" that way it can only be accessed from your local computer.

Comment: WAMP's phpmyadmin is configured to allow root with no password. `Allow from all` would open the database to the public.

Comment: The real problem is that wamp is binding to an IPv6 address. The fix: just add `Allow from ::1`

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan +1!  `Allow from ::1`  worked for me, that's all `Allow from all` was doing so I removed it in the practice of good security :)

Comment: A more security conscious effort would be to modify the hosts file (C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc) on the server machine to read `127.0.0.1    localhost` which then will interpret the localhost part as the local machine's IP address.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan please make an answer to represent your comment! A lot of people need this information and may not find it otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: I my case I had to change this in `httpd.conf` file. It didn't work for me on `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file.

Comment: If you encounter still forbidden error, do on top of it this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41264832/4641129 It worked for me! Everything works fine now :) Thank you colleagues

Answer (score 140):

You have to just check whether your [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server is online or not.

To put your WAMP server online, follow these steps.

1. Go to your WAMP server notification icon (in the task bar).
2. Single click on the WAMP server icon.
3. Select last option from the menu, that is, **Put Online**
4. Your server will restart automatically (in the latest versions only). Otherwise, you have to restart your server manually.

And you are DONE...

Comment: "latest versions only" will get outdated quickly. You ARE in the IT world, so please mention a version number. Plus this didn't work for me at all. Always have it online, running it as admin. Worse, have some domains working using virtual hosts but cant even access localhost or 127.0.0.1, or either with */phpmyadmin :s Stupidly strange. This is on Win8 btw. May have something to do with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate 64bit edition also installed (which includes IIS 8, will update)

Comment: My goodness, I feel stupid. I spent quite a while messing around with "Require all granted" etc. Thank you.

Comment: The Put Online option is now unavailable. To enable it, Right click on the Wamp Icon > Wamp settings > Check on the Menu item: Online/Offline, when you now left click on the icon, the 'Put Online' option will be available

Answer (score 126):

If you're using WAMP with Apache 2.4.2 or greater, you need to use `Require all` instead of `Allow` and remove `Order Deny,Allow`:

```
<Directory "f:/Projects/myproject/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*as stated in this [blog post](http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/06/fun-with-wamp-server-and-apache-2-4-2/)

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

Comment: your answer was supposed to be the best answer ! worked like a charm :)

Comment: This worked for me. WAMP Server 2.2; Apache 2.4.2; Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me (unlike other answers here including the accepted one)

Comment: In my WAMP it was set to <Directory /> and that worked until I needed to change the folder to my dropbox folder. Why was it set to <Directory /> ? This solution works great however.

Comment: @JensTörnell congratulations. Yo ujust allowed unlimited access to the root of whatever drive apache is installed on. I hope you dont actually allow access to your system from the internet.

Comment: This worked for me on apache2.4.18. You made my night, thank you!

Answer (score 42):

Just use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost (no changes to the configuration file are required).

System:

- Windows 7
- wampserver2.2d-x64

This works:

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
```

This one fails:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

Comment: The why is because localhost is resolved as an IPv6 address, whereas wamp default config only allows the IPv4 loopback address.

Answer (score 36):

I just had the same problem. It turns out that my installation of Windows is using the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`. To solve this, I opened `httpd.conf` and changed the following line:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

to:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Now I can access the server through `localhost`. Whatever you do, don't remove the `Deny from all from` the line above, or anyone on your network can gain access to your web server (unless that's what you want of course).

Comment: I also had to make that change to all the aliases, by the way. To edit aliases, go to: "[wamp icon]->Apache->Alias directories->[alias-url]->edit alias"

Comment: I executed `ping localhost` on my cmd terminal and got `Reply from ::1: time<1ms`. It seems my Win7 machine is resolving localhost with an IPv6 address. Your solution did the trick. I agree, this should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: Awesome!!!! I had the same problem on my Mac (MAMP) and now it works! You saved my day, dude!:D

Comment: In `httpd.conf` doesn't work for me, instead when I do the same thing in `phpmyadmin.conf` it works!

Comment: I think this answer should be edited, as the correct file to edit is `wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf`, and not `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 21):

If you are on Windows 7 or 8 then Apache might be seeing the connections coming from "::1" which is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1.

You can check this by looking in the Apache Access Log (reachable from the WAMP menu)

```
::1 - - [20/Dec/2012:21:35:04 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 403 213
```

The ::1 at the start is the clients address. The 403 at the end is the Access Denied code.

The answers above will remove all restrictions and open phpmyadmin to all, but if you still want to restrict phpmyadmin to your machine only (generally a good idea) then under the line...

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

..add the following:

```
Allow from ::1
```

(edit: Added suggestion from Nukeface)

Comment: Thank you. This should be the top comment. You explain the problem, solve it, and don't introduce a massive security vulnerability to someone's server.

Comment: I've got the solution as a separate and additional line. I use "`Allow from 127.0.0.1` next line `Allow from ::1`". Just in case it switches back to IPv4 (because say me disabling IPv6)

Answer (score 10):

Change

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

in your `httpd.conf` file. It will bind [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) to a specific [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and port.

Answer (score 8):

I found that using localhost would not work properly to allow local access from the server.  I had to use 127.0.0.1.

In phpmyadmin.conf this did not work:

```
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
```

this did work:

```
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

I am using WampServer Version 2.2

Comment: Thats probably because you dont have a properly configured HOSTS file, set that up correctly and you will be able to use localhost

Answer (score 8):

For Apache 2.4.2:

In httpd.conf:

Change

```
Require local
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to run my server online and not under localhost / 127.0.0.1 and had the forbidden message. I am running the WAMP 2.2 server ([Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) 2.4.2 / [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) 5.4.3 / [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) 5.5.24) on Windows 7 64 bit. What worked for me is the following:

1. Press the startup WAMP icon in the menu
2. Choose Apache folder
3. Choose the file `httpd.conf`
4. Under the Directory tab section (section with "# Online --> Require all granted" text), I had the "Require local" option which I changed to "Require all granted"
5. Restart all services of the WAMP

Again, it worked for me and from this thread I understand that there are many cases in which you may get the above error message so if mine does not work, try other solutions.

Good luck.

(I hope it helps someone like it helped me. I did not find any one of the solutions above working for me.)

Comment: You sir, solved a problem I spent my whole weekend trying to solve. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

1.change **D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf** near line 279

```
Require local 

 into 

Require all granted
```

2.change like this in **D:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf** from existing one

```
   <Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride all
       Require all granted
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

3.Click to **Restart All services** in wamp.

4.Click **put online** in wamp.

5.Again Click to **Restart All services** in wamp.

Hope it Helps..

Answer (score 4):

I fixed that problem before. It can happen due to many reasons, so **you can use some or all of the next steps** (opening mentioned files using any text editor, like [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)).

If you install WAMP in C:\wamp

**1-** Open file **C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf**

**Note**: you may have a different Apache version than *Apache 2.2.22*, so you need to write it instead.

Search for: **Directory "C:/wamp/www/"**. You will find something similar to this:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
   # maybe there is some comments here ...
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Be sure that **Allow from all** is exists and not outcommented.

**2-** Open file **C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf**.

Make sure that

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1  
</Directory>
```

Change **Allow from 127.0.0.1** to **Allow from all**.

You can remove **Deny from all** or comment it out by adding # at the beginning of the line, but you have to make sure that **Allow from all** is the last line of code just before `</Directory>`.

Note: you may have a different version than phpMyAdmin 3.5.1.

**To use localhost/phpmyadmin instead of 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin**:

Open file C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf. Add the following at the end of it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4):

**If WampServer works in the computer it is installed but not on another device in your network (e.g.: from your phone) with the 'You don't have permission to access  on this server.' try the following.**

1.
Edit the httpd-vhosts.conf (`C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`), so it looks like this:

```
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2.
Edit the phpmyadmin.conf (`C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`), so it looks like this:

```
<Directory "d:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.9/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
```

3.
Restart WampServer services

Comment: for me applying step 1 (and 3) were all it took.  This isn't a flaw, it's by design.  For best practices see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810669/why-wamp-server-put-online-offline-option-is-missing

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution to this would be to find phpmyadmin.conf file and then find below code inside it,

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

AllowOverride all

    Order Deny,Allow

Deny from all

Allow from 127.0.0.1

</Directory>
```

Change "Deny from all" to "Allow from all".

OR

Follow below link to get better understanding on how to do it,

[WAMP says Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server Windows 7 or 8](http://www.ultechspot.com/windows-8/wamp-says-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-access-phpmyadmin-server-windows-7-or-8)

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

For Apache 2.4.2 the solution is: 
in httpd.conf on line 265 change Require none to Require all granted.
That's all.

Answer (score 2):

I had commented out the ::1 line in my hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

Even I faced the same issue with my domain. If I gave an IP address it was working. But with a domain name it was not.

Then I checked my [DNS A record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#Resource_records). The domain had multiple entries with different IP addresses assigned. I removed all the wrong values, and it worked. Just one more check list if anyone faces a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just edit the file "c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf"

like this

```
<Directory "C:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: `C:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.5.1/` is not a file, and this question already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a dramatically better alternative approach to the problem :)

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me. I edited the correct path of the file, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

In `WAMP 3.1.4 x64` I solved updating the file `C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` from this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.3/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.3/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

to this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.3/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.3/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
    Require all granted

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

And finally restarting all WAMP services.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that the phpMyAdmin version was specified wrongly in the `phpmyadmin.conf` file. You may check that:

1. Go to wamp/apps/**phpmyadmin3.x.x**: notice the file name - what version you are currently using?
2. Open file wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf:

   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride all
           Order Deny,Allow
           Allow from all

Check the first line (directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.x.x/") is the file name exactly the same as your actual file name.

Make sure the directory file name is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in your URL, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My Apache configuration file looked like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/vtigercrm"
  <Directory "/"
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's how I fixed it:

The issue was that I specified the `Directory` as `"/"` (that is root folder on my server) instead of `"C:/wamp64/www/vtigercrm/"`, which is where I have my website files.

I modified my configuration this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  mywebsite.com
  ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/vtigercrm"
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/myvtigercrm/"
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set up my password... And that's how I got locked out from localhost. They should fix this...

Anyway, be careful with random advice. They all may or may not work. But some advice will lock you out even further. The one that worked for me:

Type "`http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`" in the address bar.

Then I discovered that `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` also works.

However, before that, out of desperation I had...

I deleted the files, I uninstalled WAMP, deleted temporary cookies, and installed WAMP again. It still doesn't accept "localhost" (and I am tired after a day trying to access WAMP), but the 127.0.0.1 and the localhost/phpmy... work. I am happy to see the page back. And start working again.

If you read this thread all the way to here means you are probably in a big problem... Windows 8, WAMP (wampserver 2.2). I wonder what it needs to get back access to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

What was going on with my setup was that WAMP was binding to an IPv6 Address (and every subsequent time I reinstalled WAMP).

To fix this, I went into `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` and added the line `Allow from ::1`

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be 127.0.0.1 is not linked to localhost. Check your 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' file. It should have a line like this:

*# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

127.0.0.1       localhost*

Answer (score 0):

So *all* of these answers are basically the same one. They only address one idea: it has to be [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) related. Well, that is not the only part of this it turns out. After many changes, I was getting nowhere reading the next "same answer" hoping that it would just go my way.

What did the trick for me was to adjust my versions of [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server). I think what the deal was, is that the one of the configuration files get a path off or that the install due to [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) may have been messed up `/` or `/` or `/etc`. And so forcing a version change readdresses everything from your firewall to bad configurations.

In fact, when I switched back to Apache 2.4.2 it goes back to being a forbidden. And as soon as I go back to Apache 2.4.4 it comes back up. That rules out local network issues.  I just wanted to point out that all of the answers here are the same and that I have been able to kill the forbidden by changing the Apache version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) is corrupted!
there were:

```
localhos 127.0.0.1

localhost 127.0.0.1

localhos 127.0.0.1
localhos 127.0.0.1
```

The result is that `localhost` is not defined.

Solution: edit the hosts file with admin rights and correct to only one entry:

```
localhost 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case a **WAMP** server was installed before on my pc, so when installing the new one some files not overwritten, all you have to do in that case is to go to the **C:\** and delete the whole **WAMP** folder then install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are logged in as **root** or user with privileges. Just to be sure, logout and login again with root/no-password.

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of WAMP I somehow had a "deny all" in my `.htaccess` file. If nothing else works, please check there too.

Answer (score 0):

If your WAMP icon is not green try:
Left Click WAMP Icon > MySQL > Services > Install Service

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Wampserver 3 64bit version 3.0.0, the path to the phpmyadmin4.5.2 directory in the phpmyadmin.conf file was wrong. For some reason the apps directory is inside the scripts directory. So I entered the correct paths as shown below. Then you probably need to restart Apache and reload the page.

I changed:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.2/"

<Directory "C:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.2/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
    Require local

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

To:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/wamp64/scripts/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.2/"

<Directory "C:/wamp64/scripts/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.2/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
    Require local

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

after making your alias in wamp server follow this steps :

1- open wamp installation folder and open alias folder such as c:/wamp/alias

2- open phpMyAdmin.conf

3- change Require local to Require all granted

4- save file

5- for your aliases : open your alias config file such as test.conf in same folder

6- copy all content of Directory tag in phpMyAdmin.conf that are something such as below :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require all granted
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
      Allow from localhost
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

8-in your alias config file paste number 5 copied texts instead of Directory tag.

9- restart your apachi server by clicking on restart all services .

that worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Everyting I have tried. Finally I understood it was problem with the port change.
So given proper port in **httpd-vhosts.conf**
If anybody going though same problem, will be helpful.

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All 
        require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can access through

> http://127.0.0.1:PortNumber/

if you don't want to change config files