# Wamp server Forbidden

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I installed latest WAMP 2.2d x64 on a new computer (no previous or uninstalled/reinstalled wamp versions).

Right after installation, running the wamp server and putting it online (else localhost is also forbidden) i try to open phpmyadmin.

I get an error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
```

I dont know why that is happening. I havent changed ANY settings yet. On my other computer i run older version of wampserver, and as far as i remember, there were not any problems with running phpmyadmin or localhost after installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wamp server might not be having permissions to access the phpmyadmin directory.
right click and run wamp server as administrator.

have you installed wamp and phpmyadmin in program files ?

If yes, I would suggest you to uninstall and install it directly under C: or somewhere else.

UPDATE:

Check this out.

[WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this)

Comment: D:/wamp is the installation folder.
And no, unfurtunately it still doesnt work.

Comment: Install XAMPP instead of WAMP or use IPv6 `::1:`

Comment: Sorry this doesnt work for me either, have it working on some local domains, not on others. Clearly something in either win8 or wamp isn't compatible with one another from the get-go as this hasnt happened in win7.

Answer (score 5):

Left click on the icon and then "Go online" (otherwise when you point at WAMP icon it says server offline although the icon is green)

Answer (score 3):

Following change is need to solve this problem

From the WampServer icon, left click, select Apache > Alias Directories > .../phpmyadmin/ > Edit alias to open the alias configuration file:

```
    <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
```

to modify following line(add ::1)

```
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

again restart wamp check solve this.

Comment: This worked for me! I'm using WampServer 2.2 on Windows 8.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing localhost/phpmyadmin/ to 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/