# WAMP Server ERROR "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server."

Tags: php, wamp

Hi Friends previously I am using XAMP Server but when I install joomla Templates it creates alots of error. Now I installed the WAMP, but the issues are:
1. I can access with 127.0.0.1, but I cant access with "localhost". 
2  When i access phpmyadmin i get this error.

Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

```
 Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#        Order Deny,Allow
#   Deny from all
#   Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#        Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all
#
```

> After changing, it will look like this

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

> After this just restart Wamp

Comment: On behalf of Sreeraj, Check the path containing phpmyadminversion number in Change the file content of c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf to the following. and the starting point..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Go to `C:\wamp\alias`. Open the file `phpmyadmin.conf` and change

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

problem solved

Comment: "problem solved" and added another bigger one. Now phpMyAdmin (the database) is public and anyone can connect to it. Good job.

Comment: `Allow from ::1` is the correct solution on systems where localhost points to an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 26):

Change httpd.conf file as follows:

from

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank god for someone who doesn't post the answer to the same question over and over again.

Comment: VERY BAD IDEA. When this guy decides he wants his friends to see what he has done and he port forwards his router. This gives Apache access to your whole disk, should you get hacked its a free pass to disaster.

Comment: solve my problem on local server, if you do not like `Require all granted` in httpd.conf, throw the setting into you Alias.(I set this in my Alias' conf)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Anything better to suggest?

Comment: @Odys That depends on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ImranKhan Worst possible answer. dont do this see other comements

Answer (score 13):

So none of the above stuff worked for me. Except this:
edit httpd.conf,

find the line

```
Listen 80
```

and change to

```
listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

if you are running windows 8, its got something to do with using ipv6 instead of ipv4

Comment: This was the solution for me after trying all of the above and more. Thank you.

Comment: @4Dev Then your issue was probably that you did not have this line `::1 localhost` in your HOSTS file. If the browser attempts to use the IPV6 network which they do more and more now this is required. The `listen 0.0.0.0:80` just tells apache to ONLY Listen on the IPV4 network

Comment: Great. Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Go to C:\wamp\alias.
 Open the file phpmyadmin.conf and add

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from MACHINE_IP
```

Comment: I think `Allow Override` should be `AllowOverride`

Answer (score 7):

Change in following file  \bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf

```
Replace Listen 80 with Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Replace

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Replace

## onlineoffline tag - don't remove

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

with

## onlineoffline tag - don't remove

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

in  \wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf
replace

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.10.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.10.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

Tested on windows localhost.
**Note :** Please consider RigsFolly's comment also.

Comment: **Never ever** amend the section starting `<Directory />` to `Require all granted` That allows a hacked Apache access to the whole disk !!!!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Did you mean this c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.10.1/ should not be added in <Directory/> tag ?

Comment: No! The section that starts `<Directory />` that is the section that controls access to the root of the drive Apache is installed on. Standard practice with Apache, lock everything out, then allow access ONLY WHERE IT IS NEEDED

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, I am not getting, could you elaborate more or add code to comment.

Comment: This part of your answer `<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>` You should never make that `Allow from all`

Comment: Ok got it, I will try to find correct way and update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For WampServer 2.2 with Apache 2.4.2 I ended up with:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require local
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, I opened `httpd.conf` and changed the following line:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

to:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Comment: Make sure skype is not running. Skype also causes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server
```

Some help about this:

First check you installed a fresh wamp or replace the existing one. If it's fresh there is no problem, For done existing installation.

Follow these steps.

1. Open your wamp\bin\mysql directory
2. Check if in this folder there is another folder of mysql with different name, if exists delete it.
3. enter to remain mysql folder and delete files with duplication.
4. start your wamp server again. Wamp will be working.

Comment: Totally not necessary. Wamp is designed to allow you to have multiple versions of Apache/Php/Mysql on the same system and switch between them. See answer using Listen 0.0.0.0:80 to make apache listen only on IPV4

Answer (score 2):

just add following line in wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf 
Allow from ::1

so it will look something like this depending your phpmyadmin version.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

If its possible uninstall wamp then run installation as administrator then change you mysql.conf file like that

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Not: Before I reinstall as admin the solution above didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Change the file content of `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` to the following.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here my WAMP installation is in the c:\wamp folder. Change it according to your installation.

Previously, it was like this:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Restart your Apache server after making these changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your apache config file (../bin/apachex.y.z/cong/httpd.conf)

Just change

< Directory "c:/wamp/www/" >
...
...

    "Require local" ===> "Require all granted"

< /Directory >

This allows other pc's to access (to read) your web folder.

Comment: **BAD SOLUTION** This will have the effect of allowing access to phpmyadmin and therefore ALL YOUR DATABASES to any ip i.e. the world! leave it as `Require local` and if you want to allow access from another PC on your internal networks add something like this `Require ip 192.168.0`

Answer (score 0):

I had done below changes for new **phpmyadmin4.0.4** in `httpd.conf` file

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and `phpmyadmin.conf`

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and restart my server.

Comment: **Never ever** amend the section starting `<Directory />` to `Require all granted` That allows a hacked Apache access to the whole disk !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, or where unsafe (as some pointed out, using `Allow from all` can make your files and data accessible to the outside world).

Open the `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file and change

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1  ::1
```

Explanation:

- On most computer systems, localhost resolves to the IP address 127.0.0.1, which is the most commonly used IPv4 loopback address, **and to the IPv6 loopback address ::1** (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)
- The resolution of the name localhost into one or more IP addresses is configured by the following lines in the operating system's hosts file:

  ```
  127.0.0.1    localhost
  ::1          localhost
  ```
- to see your hosts file, go to `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS`
- notice the above lines are commented out with the note: `# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.`

On my machine, on Win7, I also noticed the following:

- `localhost\phpmyadmin` did not work on Chrome, but worked on IE11
- `127.0.0.1\phpmyadmin` worked on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

comment Require local from httpd.conf

"#Require local"