# Insufficient File Permissions on folder

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, file-permissions

I am getting the **You don't have permission to access /phpMyEdit/phpMyEdit.class.php on this server.** error when trying to directly link here.

http://reports.caredatapro.com/phpMyEdit/phpMyEdit.class.php

Both the subfolder and file exist, and their permissions modified to 766.

What else am I missing here in checking?

Comment: Try `777` permissions. `766` excludes execute for non-owners, and Apache might need it. (I don’t remember :P)

Comment: That's a 403.  Check the error log.

Comment: obviously you do not have the rights to access it. If you are running apache then `sudo chown -R apache /path`... or maybe your script is running under different user like `nobody`, then change owner accordingly

Comment: The OS: Apache 2.2.14 (It shows this on page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file is for including, not for displaying a page. The file you want to browse to is the 'setup' file:  http://reports.caredatapro.com/phpMyEdit/phpMyEditSetup.php

That is what you use to generate the file that you will then use to browse/edit/delete your data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link can help you to solve your problem:
[Link One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600795/wamp-server-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on)
[Link Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

It does not take a long time to read them and.

most of the time you only need to edit two files:

> 1 - httpd.conf
>
> 2 - phpmyadmin.conf

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the account's conf files so I'm at the mercy of the web host. Sound articles all the same, however.

Comment: have you tried to put a simple php file with just one `echo` command in it in the same folder as:
[link](http://reports.caredatapro.com/phpMyEdit/)
and check if you get same error or not?

Comment: I just uploaded a basic file with `echo time()` and I get the same permissions error.

Comment: I changed the file permissions to 777 with no success. I then changed the folder to 777 and I now get a 500 error on the page. All I have for code is `<?php echo time(); ?>` which should work anywhere.