# Php website virtual host

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm new to php, I did installed xampp-win32-1.8.2-2-VC9-installer on my window7 desktop pc. PHP page run from C:\xampp\htdocs but when i create virtual host and tried to access php file in d:\web\ it shows access forbidden.

**my host file code**
127.0.0.1  localhost1

**my httpd-vhost file code**

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost1:80>
  DocumentRoot "d:/web/test.php"
  ServerName localhost1    
<Directory "d:/web/test.php">
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know now where i have to change

Comment: Did you restarted your apache after changes?

Comment: Take a look at related questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600795/wamp-server-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on

Answer (score 0):

It's a file permissions derived issue. Try changing NTFS permissions in "C:/xampp/htdocs" to allow read and execute permissions to the user that is running the web server, you should be able to see who that user is in the Apache configuration file, tipically "apache" which is the equivalent to IUSR in IIS.