# No permission to access my folders wampservers www folders

Tags: php, codeigniter, wampserver

I am able to access my localhost as well as phpmyadmin for wamp server but I have really struggled to access my folders in wamp servers www folder. Any time i try i get the following error

```
**Forbidden**
You dont have permission to access /folder/folder on this server.
```

I imported the files I am trying to run locally from my host and they are written in codeignitor.

Comment: you have to change the permission to that folder, or you have to change the configuration of your apache

Comment: Let's try this existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600795/wamp-server-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on

Comment: I have tried the answers provided but seems not work still

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi WAMPServer the W stands for Windows, permissions are rarely an issue on windows

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 2.5.