# Wampserver root privileges error

Tags: root, wampserver, privileges

By accident I deleted all root users in msql/wampsever and then i can't acces phpmyadmin !

I tried to launch mysql console and connect to root .. It works so i don't know what i should do !

phpMyadmin : "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server."

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Can you show us your /alias/phpmyadmin.conf file? It should have something along the lines of:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

See [this post](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,80911).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your wamp back by following two steps:

**Step 1: Set privileges to mysql**

**i.** Open command prompt and navigate to mysql bin folder which is usually present in

"C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin"

Execute the below set of mysql commands with appropriate changes to set the new password

```
MYSQL -U root -P
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('YourNewPassword') WHERE User='root';
```

**Step 2: Configure the above set privileges to phpadmin/wamp**

**i.** Locate "config.inc" file in the wamp folder, typically it is present in

"C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1"

**ii.** Open it up using standard text editor such as notepad etc.

[image: Screen shot of "config.inc" highlighting user and password]

**iii.** Edit the values of user/password to what you have setup in the previous step.

**iv.** Save the config.inc file and do not forget to restart all the services by rightclick wamp on the