# WAMP not displaying my files

Tags: php, wampserver

I started wamp server and my browser is not showing my files in the local host and I am not sure what I should do about it?

I have installed IIS in my system one month before.I have stopped the IIS in the IIS manager.I ca view the phpmyadmin page in the browser.When I browse for `localhost`,The page with the image of IIS is shown.If I browse for `localhost/my_file` it is showing `You don't have permission to access /my_file on this server.`I have done which is described in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Please help me

Comment: try to change the port of WAMP

Comment: Are your files located in an accessible map (like www)?

Comment: @ToonCasteele Ya its present inside www

Comment: Check http.hosts file and try restarting wamp, also make sure the permissions of the www directory are correct.

Comment: @chriz There is no such file in my wamp

Answer (score 1):

Edit http.conf file in notepad usually located in C:\wamp\Apache2\conf .
then do either CTL+F or go to EDIT/FIND from the notepad menubar. this will open FIND window. type 80 in the 'Find What' box and click find next. replace 80 to whichever port to want apache to listen to. you may have to change to two or more places depending on your configuration. and then restart your apache server. Apache should listen to the port you set in the http.conf file. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are saying that i should change every 80 to my desired value

Comment: yeah, and the url will be localhost:your port number

Comment: Its redirecting to google chrome and showing "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost"

Comment: restart the wamp server and try, if your port number is 90 url will be http://localhost:90

Comment: There are 3 places in my httpd.conf file.They are ServerName localhost:88,#Listen 12.34.56.78:88,Listen 88.I have changed it to 88.It was 80 in the beginning

Comment: http://localhost:88
wot your browser showing now. make sure you restart the wampserver

Comment: its showing This link appears to be broken.I have restarted my wampserver