# Cannot access phpmyadmin in wamp server.

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

It says,

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

I am already using an exsisting project using wamp (/localhost/phploginsession/), for database creation and works, but not through phpmyadmin. Please help me use phpmyadmin for my project.

Thank you,
Franklin Vaz.

Comment: The directory on the webserver probably doesn't have permissions to access it, alternatively there could be a config blocking it.

Comment: Look in the /alias/ directory of your WAMP install, you may find different permissions for PHPMyAdmin in a file there. It would help to know if you are attempting to access it via `localhost/phpmyadmin/` or something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Answer (score 1):

use 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

this is happening beacause if you put your wamp server online and if someone can access your sites in a network it can't access phpmyadmin because it is 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

Comment: This is exactly the correct answer! i got t... it working now... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is binding to an IPv6 address on your version of Windows. To fix just add Allow from ::1 in c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf.
You may get advice to "Allow all" but this makes ua wamp public therefore i highly dont recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I updated the version of phpmyadmin that I was using. The line Alias /phpmyadmin "" in phpmyadmin.conf still had the folder for the old version.

Answer (score -1):

You should try 127.0.0.1 ! It might work !

Comment: what is 127.0.0.1 ??? i guess ip address. please could you be more specific, cuz m new to coding. what should i try???

Comment: I stopped Widows Features On or Off by unchecking Internet Information Services (IIS). Got help from internet, but still the prob resides. Infact i am admin to my computer, do know why this is not working with only my pc :(