# Cant modify data in database with wamp

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp

I am using wamp to to host my server on my computer and I have a webpage where, that modifys that data in a database, when ever I try to modify the data though I get this error

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /htdocs/< on this server.

with htdocs being my project folder

if anyone knows how to fix this that would be great.

thanks

Comment: Check your permissions

Comment: @christopherW you mean in my .conf files ?

Comment: I mean everywhere. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s

Comment: maybe fix the folder permission, by going to the folder and checking out the property, and set permission allowed...

Comment: @php NoOb how do i go to the folder permision?

Comment: @user2109242 `C:\wamp` then property->security and check if permission to access the file is denied/accepted else instead of going to `localhost/wamp...` try `127.0.0.1/wamp..`

Comment: What operating system are we talking about here?

Comment: @ChristianMark Windows 8

Comment: Why are you accessing the wamp thru `htdocs`? try `localhost/` or `127.0.0.1/` on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Wamp does not use a htdocs folder by default, it sounds like you have a very messed up system.

Do you have another Apache service running? Wamps apache service is called 'wampapache' and NOT Apache.

Did you install apache some ther way before installing wamp, if so Uninstall it, ditto MySQL if you had that installed before installing wamp.