# Unable to setup a local environment with WAMP? (Laravel Framework)

Tags: apache, laravel, localhost, wamp, laravel-4

I have been looking for information on google, laravel forums and youtube all day but no luck, hopefully someone can help.

I am currently trying to setup a website which was built by a web design company on my local machine but I it doesn't seem to be letting me do so.

At the moment the things I have done to get the website running locally are:

1. Installed a WAMP server
2. Changed the httpd.conf file to include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
3. Changed the httpd-vhosts.conf file to include the following:

DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\ryl\public"

ServerName rateyourlecturer.dev

1. Edited my drivers\etc\hosts.txt file to include the following:

127.0.0.1       localhost

127.0.0.1       rateyourlecturer.dev

But when I go  and type rateyourlecturer.dev into the address bar the following error message appears "403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server."

If anyone can help me solve this problem I will be really grateful.

Comment: Check this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s

Comment: @MostafaAdly That is a different problem. I have seen numerous posts like that today all which don't work

Comment: Sounds like your web root is the application directory instead of the public directory within it. You need to adjust, in your conf/extra/http-vhosts.conf file, where the app is so the .dev URL  points to public/index.php (the public directory) rather than the application directory

Comment: I added a new VHost directly to httpd.conf, now and it ran smoothly. Running latest WAMP with Win8.

Comment: @Arda what do you mean when you say you added a new vhost to httpd.conf? can you show me what you did as I'm still stuck.

Comment: @user2701080 posting as answer, it's too long to type here.

Answer (score 1):

I simply added these codes in my httpd.conf, and it worked well:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@me.com
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project_name/public"
ServerName project_name.dev
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/project_name/public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

More information, [here](http://www.terrymatula.com/development/2012/setting-up-a-virtual-host-for-wamp-and-laravel/) (it's for laravel 3, but vhost solution works for l4 etc, too)

Answer (score 0):

**Follow its strictly,its 100% work **

1.you have to put laravel in  C:\wamp\www folder

2.then u have to go application/config ....open application.php and change url='';

3.change key='K3u4UsHKh7AjSitP9VLTMtbd1mjvdzmQ'

4.then u have to go int C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra  folder then
  open <<=== httpd-vhosts.conf ===>> file and paste below this line into that folder

DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/laravel/public
    ServerName xxxxx.dev

5.then go   C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  folder and open <<=== hosts ===>> file then paste
 127.0.0.1       xxxxx.dev

6.then go C:\wamp\www\laravel\public folder ...and then open a.htaccess ..then paste 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
7.Then u have to go >> C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf <<  this directory & open httpd.conf & comment out this line

## Virtual hosts

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

8.then go wamp server .....start it ..and click rewrite mode in apache->apache module..then restart wamp server

9.then go ur browser and write xxxxx.dev/docs  ...