# How to allow remote access to my WAMP server for Mobile(Android)

Tags: php, networking, wamp, wireless

I have created a website for mobile using PHP and jQuery. It works on my PC but now I want to test it with my Android device. How can I do that?

How can I access a WAMP server's IP from my Android device?

My mobile and PC are connected within the same router. Should I directly connect to my PC or can I do that through the router?

I have searched about it and found that I have to change permissions in phpmyadmin.conf but still it does not work. Any ideas why doesn't it work?

My httpd.config has something like this.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.0.104
</Directory>
```

192.168.0.104 is my android device's IP.

Comment: My simple put is to make WAMP online via `Put online` command in system tray menu.
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116143,116143

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume you are using windows. Open the command prompt and type `ipconfig` and find out your local address (on your pc) it should look something like `192.168.1.13` or `192.168.0.5` where the end digit is the one that changes. It should be next to IPv4 Address.

If your WAMP does not use virtual hosts the next step is to enter that IP address on your phones browser ie `http://192.168.1.13` If you have a virtual host then you will need root to edit the hosts file.

If you want to test the responsiveness / mobile design of your website you can change your user agent in chrome or other browsers to mimic a mobile.

See http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html.

Edit: Chrome dev tools now has a mobile debug tool where you can change the size of the viewport, spoof user agents, connections (4G, 3G etc).

If you get forbidden access then see this question [WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s). Basically, change the occurrances of `deny,allow` to `allow,deny` in the `httpd.conf` file. You can access this by the WAMP menu.

To eliminate possible causes of the issue for now set your config file to

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

As thatis working for my windows PC, if you have the directory config block as well change that also to allow all.

Config file that fixed the problem:

https://gist.github.com/samvaughton/6790739

Problem was that the /www apache directory config block still had deny set as default and only allowed from localhost.

Comment: i have tried using ip-address but still it says forbidden 
& you dont have permission to access on this server.

Comment: @Pulah Nandha See edited answer.

Comment: i have done this. still its not working.

Comment: Post your http.conf file. This is for the web server and not phpmyadmin yes?

Comment: http.config or httpd.config?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38471/discussion-between-pulah-nandha-and-sam)

Comment: Sorry but it didn'w work. I have the same setting in httpd.conf.

Comment: @LuisArriojas this answer is nearly 3 years old, I have no idea about the current WAMP climate unfortunately.