# How can I connect my other computer to phpMyAdmin localhost?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have another pc over at my fiance's house & I'm trying to connect to my home computer's myphpadmin (localhost), database 'users'. Is there any way I can do it or is it impossible?

& is there a way I can make it accessible to all ip address's? I need it for a couple friends & I to work on a game together.

`I guess I left out 1 part. I used 1 method I could find. The no-ip beings I have a dynamic IP address. I tried to connect & it wouldn't let me.`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask this. I'd suggest http://serverfault.com/ but, you don't seem to have bothered to look into what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Connect both computer to using lan or wi-fi. or configure network.

now check ip-address of your php hosted pc.

if your computer is connected with same netwrk then you can access via ip-address/phpmyadmin

ex. 192.168.x.x/phpmyadmin.

make sure both computer must in same network.

Comment: We're on two separate networks. I'm at my house. She is at hers.
is there a way to allow all connections so I don't have to keep allowing it... I know it's not recommended. But if it's possible, this is for a project between my fiance, a few friends & I.

Comment: then you cant directly connect. may be there are some software (MAY BE). but as per my knowledge it challenging task. i only say that best of luck.

Comment: check this out. this might helps you if you are in same network.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132059/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-my-wamp-server-for-mobileandroid
this is for android mobile but same way you can access on pc as well.

Answer (score 0):

if your system is an a  local network then it's possible ..
open httpd.conf   file and change the below code

Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    #Deny from all

**change it to**

    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

and restart the wampserver...