# Wamp Local host blank. Port 80 is clear

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I've checked in the cmd, I've checked into just about everything and port 80 is good to go but local host is still blank. I followed a tutorial to move the wamp install to dropbox, and on my desktop it loads fine. However when it's on my laptop localhost is blank. I'm at a loss.

I fixed this issue. In case anyone in the future runs into if:
Use Wampservers watch :80 from the apache menu to see what is using it.

For me it was IIS. You have to use a command line code to end it. Open CMD and run:

```
NET STOP IISADMIN /Y
```

If you are running Windows 8 add

```
"Allow from ::1"
```

beneath

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

in both httpd.conf and phpmyadmin.conf.

Comment: open wampserver->www->index.php and write `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and run localhost again and tell what display there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to use wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80

This will launch a command window and tell you is anything is using port 80.

Then rather than killing it ( if its a service that is automatically started it will just be back again after a reboot ) attempt to reconfigure it so it no longer uses port 80.

or

Try this link

```
http://ye5.blogspot.in/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html
```

Comment: I tried that. It was kind of a perfect storm.

Port 80 was used by IIS, and I'm on Win 8 so I was running ipv6 so localhost wouldn't allow access so I had to follow this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13981168/2014858

I'm win8 on my desktop where wamp worked from the start so not sure what hapened. I fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Ah thanks for this. It reported "no information might be skype", and lo and behold I forgot skype was running.

Answer (score 0):

Click on wampmanager icon  -> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80

After you can see Port 80 is used by any other application in your system

Then rather than killing service ( if its a service that is automatically started it will just be back again after a reboot ) you need to attempt reconfigure it, so it no longer uses port 80.

---

Use below link to resolved your problem.

http://ye5.blogspot.in/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html

Answer (score 0):

Start > Run > services.msc > disable "World Wide Publishing" and restart all wamp