# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server, WAMP Error

Tags: apache, windows-8, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I have installed **wamp** on **windows 8** and received above error whenever I go to localhost or phpmyadmin. After much searching I found many answers which includes modifying the httpd.conf to `Allow from All` etc. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) link shows such a common answer with further information.

My problem is that many have argued that it gives permission to all users to access phpMyAdmin and it is insecure and vulnerable etc. I want to create perfectly secure WAMP server and is it OK if I do this?

Can someone please provide me with some reference or information?

Comment: See here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I find the best (and least frustrating) path is to start with `Allow from All`, then, when you know it will work that way, scale it back to the more secure `Allow from 127.0.0.1` or `Allow from ::1` (localhost).

As long as your firewall is configured properly, `Allow from all` shouldn't cause any problems, but it is better to only allow from localhost if you don't need other computers to be able to access your site.

Don't forget to restart Apache whenever you make changes to httpd.conf. They will not take effect until the next start.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started, there is lots of documentation available online.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very clear, timely and descriptive.

Comment: indeed. thanks for simple answer devoid of patronizing attitude towards those of us who know less.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, was having troubles with a new install of WAMP 2.5. Blog link was key to solving my issue.

Comment: For anyone that looks at this after me, the linked above blog post is no longer there, but here is a link to it on a different server: http://www.hieule.info/web/solve-the-denied-access-problem-when-using-wamp-server-2-on-windows-8/

Answer (score 28):

**1.**

first of all
Port 80(or what ever you are using) and 443 must be allow for both TCP and UDP packets. To do this, create 2 inbound rules for TPC and UDP on Windows Firewall for port 80 and 443.
(or you can disable your whole firewall for testing but permanent solution if allow inbound rule)

**2.**

#### If you are using WAMPServer 3 See bottom of answer

#### For WAMPServer versions <= 2.5

You need to change the security setting on Apache to allow access from anywhere else, so edit your `httpd.conf` file.

Change this section from :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
```

To :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
```

if "Allow from all" line not work for your then use "Require all granted"
then it will work for you.

#### WAMPServer 3 has a different method

In version 3 and > of WAMPServer there is a Virtual Hosts pre defined for `localhost` so dont amend the `httpd.conf` file at all, leave it as you found it.

Using the menus, edit the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

[image]

It should look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Amend it to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note:if you are running wamp for other than port 80 then VirtualHost will be like VirtualHost *:86.(86 or port whatever you are using) instead of VirtualHost *:80

**3.**
**Dont forget to restart All Services of Wamp or Apache after making this change**

Comment: This should have been chosen as the correct answer. @Hassan you saved my life!

Comment: thanks glad to know that it helpful also for other peoples,i mixed all research and methods into one answer so that it save other peoples time for searching

Comment: Searched for quite a while before finding this working solution. Confirmed works for 3.1. Thank you kindly @HassanSaeed !

Comment: Glad that someone explained about `WAMP 3`. All other answers on SO become invalid for this version.

Answer (score 11):

By default wamp sets the following as the default for any directory not explicitly declared:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

For me, if I comment out the line that says `Require all denied` I started having access to the directory in question.  I don't recommend this.

Instead in the directory directive I included `Require local` as below:

```
<Directory "C:/GitHub/head_count/">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

**NOTE**: I was still getting permission denied when I only had `Allow from all`.  Adding `Require local` helped for me.

Comment: This one worked for me as well - perhaps apache has changed since the OP last year . The key thing was Require local

Answer (score 8):

Adding `Allow from All` didn't worked for me. Then I tried this and it worked.

> OS: Windows 8.1
> Wamp : 2.5

I added this in the file *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin localhost@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: please see ''http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196611/create-vhost-in-wamp-2-5-in-different-directory-on-win7-returns-forbidden-error''

Answer (score -1):

This could be one solution.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";
    private static final String URL_FOR_REGISTRATION = "http://192.168.10.4/android_login_example/register.php";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private EditText signupInputName, signupInputEmail, signupInputPassword, signupInputAge;
    private Button btnSignUp;
    private Button btnLinkLogin;
    private RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        // Progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_name);
        signupInputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_email);
        signupInputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_password);
        signupInputAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_age);

        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLinkLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_link_login);

        genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_group);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                submitForm();
            }
        });
        btnLinkLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void submitForm() {

        int selectedId = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        String gender;
        if(selectedId == R.id.female_radio_btn)
            gender = "Female";
        else
            gender = "Male";

        registerUser(signupInputName.getText().toString(),
                signupInputEmail.getText().toString(),
                signupInputPassword.getText().toString(),
                gender,
                signupInputAge.getText().toString());
    }

    private void registerUser(final String name,  final String email, final String password,
                              final String gender, final String dob) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String cancel_req_tag = "register";

        progressDialog.setMessage("Adding you ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL_FOR_REGISTRATION, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    if (!error) {
                        String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi " + user +", You are successfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {



                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("gender", gender);
                params.put("age", dob);
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    }
```

Comment: plz tell me value dos not save on local host advance thanxk