# Webserver (WAMP + Wordpress) access from LAN not working properly

Tags: wordpress, wamp, lan, connectivity

i've started my first local webserver (vwware workstation) yesterday and ran into problems getting clients to connect to the wordpress-website.

I installed WAMP with default settings and added the wordpress-folder to the default www-folder and deactivated the firewall.
At first clients who tried to connect to 192.168.0.50 got the "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server" message.
Fortunately i stumbled across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377476/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-wamp-error) post #8, where you have to edit the httpd-vhosts.conf file with Require all granted. This worked partially, client access is working with the IP and http://webserver, but it's only the WAMP-Homepage. http://webserver/wordpress displays the website, but it's text-only without proper graphics and format.

My question is:

A) How can i get the website displayed properly?

B) I have another setup without WAMP but Apache, MySQL, PHP, phpMyAdmin, Wordpress installed separately. 
Clients can't connect to the website: 'firefox can't connect to the sercer localhost'.
When i try to connect from WAMP-WebserverA to WebserverB firefox displays WAMP-Homepage, which is localhost. 
Is there a way to get rid of 'localhost' redirection?

Best regards!

Comment: Show us you `httpd-vhosts.conf` and let us know what version of WAMPServer you are using please

Comment: # Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
 <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
#  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#

Comment: sorry for the format. I just changed Require local to Require all granted.This is the httpd-vhost.config of my WAMP setup. Apache Version:
    2.4.23

Comment: Create a Virtual Host for the specific project See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618