# Getting error after Wamp installation

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm getting this error msg after trying to open localhost/phpmyadmin after the installation process of Wamp:

> Forbidden
>   You don’t have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you must be administrator user on computer 
if you are admin  already .. try "run as adminminstrator"

Comment: Server-related issues should be asked on http://serverfault.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Comment: I was trying to use joomla and I'm pretty new to it and I got this error msg which I've resolved now. But thanks for the help.

Comment: I got a question ban please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably an IPV6 issue, in other words apache is listening on IPV6 and actually using the ::1 IPV6 loopback address.

If you have installed WAMP 2.4 
Change the file content of c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf from

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

To the correct Apache 2.4.x syntax for any local address

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

If you are still using WAMP 2.2.x
Change the file content of c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf from

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the httpd.conf file. In wamp just click the green "W" and select apache>httpd.conf 
then add this lines of code and see if it works (note that you have to restart the services before noticing any change)

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
 Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ignore any answer that tells you to change anything to `Allow from all` unless you actually want to allow access from ALL users on the internet.