# Directory in Wamp server is not accessible

Tags: php, android, mysql, wampserver

With reference with [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/), I want to connect my mobile to wamp server.But i am getting application crash. Manual when i create "C:\wamp\www\android_connect"
and try to access same with ip address on browser i getting

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /android_connect/ on this server.**
Error.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you access the server from _outside_ android? Have you checked the file permissions on the server?

Comment: I didn't get your point. Firstly i also tried to access same folder using browser like. My IP address\Folder name. but same error found

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s), the answers there will give you things you can try.