# Wamp not getting online in windows 8.1

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I have installed Wamp on my compuer running Windows 8.1 (64bit).
It does not going to online (green). It's still showing orange.

I already tried to configure the Web development agent service and it is still not running now.

I tested the Apache port and it shows:

```
Your port 80 is not actually used.

Press enter to exit....
```

How to start Wamp on my OS. I do not using Skype in computer.

Anybody please help me.

Thanks

Comment: `I do not using Skype in computer` is foreigner speak for I DONT HAVE SKYPE

Answer (score 1):

Start your os console as an admin then type the system command "netstat -ab", it will display all used ports on your system and which programs are using these ports.

Anas

Comment: hi anas, port 80 is not using any of the service. is there any make correction in my http.con file ?

Comment: can you test this url in your browser and post results http: // 127.0.0.1
may be IIS already using this port

Comment: try to change the port in httpd.conf file ? ex: Listen 8080
Then use http://127.0.0.1:8080
Just to be sure that's your wamp config is OK

Answer (score 0):

Secret ancient knowledge aquired via my friend, [Google](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,54968,75797):

**Step 1**:

If you are getting the "your port 80 not actually used" in Windows 8

when you test port 80 from `wamp icontray > apache > services > test port 80`

open httpd.conf from `wamp icontray > apache >httpd.conf` and locate the line

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

Make sure the line `Listen 80` is *uncommented* and is as it is above and if you had changed to `Listen 0:0:0:0:80` change it back to

```
Listen 80
```

**Step 2**:

Got to the hosts file `C:/windows/system32/Drivers/etc` and make sure it only contains `127.0.0.1 localhost` and not `::1` ie make sure its shows `#::1` if the `::1` is present

```
#::1
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

If you get an error `"403 Access forbidden"` when you try to access phpMyAdmin go to step 3

**Step 3**: (Step courtesy Peter mortensen comment posted in stackoverflow.com [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s))

Change the content of `c:/wamp/apps/alias/phpmyadmin.conf` to the following

```
<directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

NB: The phpMyAdmin remains the version you have installed mine was `c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/`

The main thing here is to remove `Deny from All` and `Allow from 127.0.0.1`

Then restart Apache server after this and you are good to go.

Comment: Not working Adelphia, its now showing mozila as "Unable to Connect"

Comment: You probly F'd up your hosts file. Go back and fix it.

Comment: in my host file it showing as  **127.0.0.1       localhost**

Comment: That is as it should be. Did you restart Apache?

Comment: yes. also my laptop. what is the error. now its showing same on the test port

Comment: test port? what test port? where does your laptop come into all this?