# Why the error "Forbidden" "You don't have permission to access / on this server." is appearing after installing wampserver2.2d on Windows 7?

Tags: wampserver

I just downloaded `wampserver2.2d-x32.exe` from source forge and installed on my machine running on Windows 7 operating system.

The setup went well. Now when I started wampserver the **W** icon has turned Green but when I click on localhost link I get following message in a browser window :

```
**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Even I tried to check phpmyadmin by hitting the link `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` then I got following message in a browser window :

```
**Forbidden**

 You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Can someone please help me in resolving these issues?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Comment: @TomToms That answer is actually pretty poor I have attempted a more accurate one below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that your browser is using the ip address `::1` the `IPV6` localhost address and WAMPServer 2.2d (being rather old now) was released before IPV6 was normally available on Windows Boxes so the httpd.conf does not contain this ip as a valid ip.

So first change the `httpd.conf` file like this ( use the menus to edit httpd.conf)

Find the `Listen` parameter it probably looks like this

```
Listen 80
```

Change it to

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Then look for this section

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
```

And change it to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

Now check the `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and make sure you have at least these entries in it

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost
```

To correct phpMyAdmin you will also have to edit the `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file in the same way, as phpMyAdmin is secured seperately in WAMPServer.

Edit `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

Look for this section :

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
```

And also add the IPV6 localhost address like this

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```