# WAMP: Forbidden access to phpmyadmin through IP

Tags: php, wamp

I installed `WAMP SERVER` on Windows 7 OS, when I launched `WAMP SERVER` icon turns green. when I hit `localhost` in browser it shows

> website declined to show webpage

also when I try to access it with `IP` address in browser, it's shows `WAMP` `index page`,

but still unable to access `PHPMYADMIN`, browser produces error:

> Forbidden, you don't have access...

Comment: Can you share your screenshot?

Comment: We are dull human creature who can not read mind ... so would you mind posting more information?

Comment: OK lets start with which version of WAMPServer you installed. Also add the contents of your HOSTS file to your question i.e. `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 0):

if you previously install WAMP and reinstalled it the it might be due to WAMP configurations. you need to set WAMP server configuration. to do so

> Change the file content of c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf to the following.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here my WAMP installation is in the c:\wamp folder. Change it according to your installation.

Previously, it was like this:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Restart your Apache server after making these changes.

**OR**

if you're accessing it via `Routed-IP` address then you MUST put you're `WAMP` online.
to do so:

Right Click Your `WAMP` icon and `put online`. then restart `WAMP`

[Source -This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)