# 403 Forbidden error when i try to access my wamp site on my laptop

Tags: wamp

I am new to WAMP and i have installed WAMP on a virtual machine and created a new directory in the WAMP folder  and shared it with my LAPTOP so that i could access it on my laptop instead of the virtual machine but when i try to access it in the browser on my laptop i get a  403 forbidden error saying You don't have permission to access /mysite/wp-admin/options-permalink.php on this server. I have seen on other sites that i need to change the permission settings for the WAMP folder but I can't see how to do it anywhere.

Comment: http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/

Comment: But in all seriousness, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8367064/1179430