# why wamp server put online/ offline option is missing?

Tags: wamp

I'm using windows 8. recently i've installed wampserver3_x86_apache2.4.17_mysql5.7.9_php5.6.15. but the put online/offlline option is missing. I did wamp manager->wamp settings->menus item online/offline. it doesn't work also. there is no green the green mark beside this option.

What to do?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Its not missing it is now an optional menu

Right click Wampmanager -> WAMPSetting -> Menu Item: Online/Offline

If you click it so there is a Tick beside it, you will see the `Online/Offline` menu on the `left click` menu.

**However it was made optional as its use is defunct.**

You should create Virtual Hosts for each of your projects, then you can amend each of those individually to control the Apache access rules.

In fact in WAMPServer 3 or greater, there is a Virtual Host defined for `localhost` so this old `Online/Offline` process wont actually do what you want.

You now have to go to the `wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` file and manually amend that entry

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted                  #<-- changed line
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This file can be edited using the wampmanager menus like this

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd-vhosts.conf
```

However it is **not recommended** to allow this sort of access to localhost. It is better to create a Virtual Hosts for each of your projects eg

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project1.dev
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www/project1
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/project1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So when is it online and when offline? Is it online when there is a check mark visible next to Online/Offline? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: @JoSmo See amended answer

Comment: Thank you, it works but it's not very safety. Is there a way to grant access only for a specific IP or network ? For example, when we ask someone to test the project ?

Comment: @Eve Yes, use `require ip 192.168.0` for example to allow anyone in that subnet OR `require ip 111.222.333.444, 111.222.333.445` for specific ips

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should solve the problem within C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf or wampserver or anything else.

You have 4 options, open only one option below.
It will works. Find below section

in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    
    AllowOverride All

    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    

    #Require all granted # put online
    #Deny from all
    #Require ip 192.168.1
    #Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Require local # put offline
</Directory>
```