# Android - How to connect an android phone to computer's localhost

Tags: java, android, localhost

I running a webserver on my computer. And I want to control and use from my android phone. (physical device)

I'm using WAMP Server on Windows 10.

Is this possible? If it is, what should i do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess "localhost" is only one of faces of Your computer. Must catch some knowledge about networks, programming etc

Comment: Can you recommend any sources about these. If there is i'll be glad to know.

Comment: Use your computer's local IP. On Windows, type `ipconfig` in console, then look for the value after "IPv4 Address". Think of "localhost" as computer-talk for "myself". Alternatively, if your computer isn't behind a router or if you have port forwarding set up, use its public IP address (easily found using [this](https://www.whatismyip.com/)).

Comment: `have a site on my computer's localhost`. Nonsense. You are running a webserver on a computer. And every device, android, linux or windows, is its own localhost. So talking about localhost does not make sense in this way.

Comment: I guess I understand what you means but my english isn't good and i don't know much about this subject.How should i say?

Comment: I already told you how you had to formulate that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the networks your client and your server are connected to.

- If you're using the emulator then just use your local ip address
- If you're using a physical device on the same local network (ex: your home wifi) then use your local ip address, make sure your server is online, and make sure  that there's no firewall stopping your server from listening to your requests
- If you're using a physical device on remote network (let's say the internet) then use your remote ip address, make sure your server is online, that there's no firewall stopping it from getting local requests, configure your router to forward external requests to the computer you're using as a server (check what ip forwarding is if you're new to this)

### Example with WAMP server running on Windows

- [You can get your local ip address by typing `ipconfig` in `cmd`](https://www.whatismyip.com/how-to-get-your-local-ip-address-on-windows-10/)
- You can get your remote ip address from this [link](http://www.formyip.com/remote-ip-tracker.php)
- To make your Apache online, chose put online on the menu show when clicking on wamp server icon (you might encounter in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810669/why-wamp-server-put-online-offline-option-is-missing))
- [Some port forwarding and firewall disabling](https://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-put-online-your-wampserver/)

Comment: I am using a physical device. What did you want to say while you are saying "make sure there's no firewall stopping it".How do i do that?

Comment: What web server are you using? What OS are you using?

Comment: WAMP server and Windows 10

Comment: `If you're using the emulator: Just use your local ip address.`. No. Then you have to use ip 10.0.2.2.

Comment: @greenapps Trust me, your local Ip address will do too.

Comment: No. The local ip address of the computer where the emulator is running on cannot be used by a client running on that emulator to connect to a server running on the computer.

Comment: The reason that it does not work is that emulator and pc are in different networks.

Comment: The local IP address will only work if both machines are connected to the same network with no firewall. You can e.g. configure them both to connect over WiFi or similar, and drop the firewall, but you should not do that unless in a very controlled environment.

Comment: @Janne Enberg. The discussion you seem to follow is about one machine. With an emulator running on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect an external device to your local development environment there are a few services that provide nice tunnels for you.

Some such services are:

- Ngrok: https://ngrok.com/
- PageKite: https://pagekite.net/
- Localtunnel: https://localtunnel.github.io/www/

What these services do is they connect a public address to your development environment via a temporary tunnel you can open at will. You don't have to configure your firewall, you don't have to have a public IP, and using them is generally rather easy. Give them a go, see which one works best for your needs.

Comment: `If you want to connect an external device to your local development environment`. Nobody wants that. OP wants to connect a client app on an Android device with a server application running on a computer.

Comment: That is exactly what that means, "external device", i.e. device other than their own computer. It sounds like they have a server application running on a computer which they develop on, and they have an application running on a phone that they want to connect to that, which is exactly the case I'm talking about.

Comment: `That is exactly what that means,`. Only in your fanthasy. If you want to say what you explained now then do so right away as your original wording makes no sense.

Comment: The original wording is perfectly fine, your failure to comprehend it does not invalidate it.

Comment: ngrok doesn't work without account creation and auth token now. localtunnel will work without any of this additional steps.