# I put wampserver 3.0.6 online but not reachable from 2nd PC

Tags: wampserver

I've [put WampServer 3.0.6 online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810669/why-wamp-server-put-online-offline-option-is-missing/36825283#36825283), updated my `http-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.comparetherapies.dev
    ServerAlias www.comparetherapies.dev
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/WAMP/WWW/comparetherapies
    <Directory  "C:/Users/steve/Dropbox/WAMP/WWW/comparetherapies">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and added a line to a second PC's `hosts` file:

```
10.0.0.14 www.comparetherapies.dev
```

where `10.0.0.14` is the IP of the first PC with WampServer.

However, when I try to load `www.comparetherapies.dev` in the second PC's browser, I receive a `connection timed out` error.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the first PC's Windows Firewall, and noticed no rule allowing Apache through the Firewall.

Adding a Windows Firewall exception on the first PC, (both private & public) for `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\httpd.exe` allowed me to view the website from the second PC.