# WAMP "You don't have permission to access /Health_1st/> on this server."

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a PHP file. In this I have created a button. when this button is pressed it directs to a PHP block where I have only inserted an ECHO statement.
But when I pressed the button I get below error.

Quote---
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /Health_1st/> on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
Un-Quote---

"Health_1st" is the folder that the files are saved (in wamp/www/)

Please help to get this solved

Comment: This sounds like either permission problem, or an apache virtual server issue.

You should post the echo code, otherwise this will be hard to determine.

Comment: The link is  <form id='login' action='<?php login_1();?>>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'> , the echo code is  echo "user_name";

Comment: so your posting data?

Comment: yes. I have inserted "ECHO" statement just to see whether the posting is done correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Comment: The lack of information here makes it hard to understand things.
You have a forbidden message.

Sooo, give the directories full permissions (chmod 0777)

in windows right click root directory, and uncheck read-only and hit apply.

you could try moving the health directory to be in the same place.
Also, if your pointing the form to a directory with an index file, try pointing to the file directly, some setups dont have index set for directories, and forbidden is cause directory services is disabled.

Comment: Hi , i got it myself solved the issue even though I am not very much clear of what has happened . So appreciate if you you could explain what has happened

Answer (score 0):

The directory index is not set, or the server has been installed in a restricted directory like program files.

Try reinstalling wamp to a new directory, OR try an alternative wamp package Like xampp (for windows)