# Can't acces phpmyadmin after creating WAMP vHost

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Today I've created a virtual host in WAMP but after that I couldn't access localhost/phpmyadmin and localhost anymore I've also tried to make a vhost for that aswell but it didn't work.

The file httpd-vhosts.conf is included correctly.

EDIT: I can access pao.dev

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pao.dev
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/pao/PAO-zwabbertje/public
    <Directory C:/wamp/www/pao/PAO-zwabbertje/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin.dev
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/
   <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**pc hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       pao.dev
127.0.0.1       phpmyadmin.dev
```

**Error:**

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Are you sure about the port you are using? Because you might be using the same port for some other application

Comment: @M3ghana The port is fine no other application is using it

Comment: Can you tell what error you are getting?

Comment: @M3ghana Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s

Comment: @M3ghana Yes I saw and tried this but it didnt work.