# Wamp Server 3.0.6 working fine as localhost, but not on network

Tags: php, wamp

I have just installed WAMP server on a server, when logged into the server, everything works fine, website is displayed as i would expect, however if i try to access the website from a remote machine I get a message

> 'Forbidden - you don't have permission to access / on this server'

I have checked the server is online and all services are running... and they are

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s?rq=1

Comment: I believe your apache is misconfigured.

Comment: Take a look into the host configuration of your apache http server. That is where the configuration is that defines what requests are accepted or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *directory* of virtualhost, change *Require local* with *Require all granted*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot your_path
    <Directory  "your_path/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

change to:

```
    <Directory  "your_path/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: If you aren't using virtual host, in your main httpd.conf file: click on Wamp icon -> apache -> httpd.conf.

Note that if you are not using virtual host, you don't have the <virtualhost tag. Just search for <Directory

Answer (score 0):

Most likely apache permissions on the vhost. Make sure it's not limited to localhost. If possible post your apache log. The error log will tell you why.

Comment: the only thing I have changed from the vanilla installation is I ticked the 'Allow virtualhost local ip's other than 127.*'

Comment: hmm.. when I try top open the httpd-vhosts.conf I get an error message - 'could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not execute run action: The system cannot find the file specified.'