# Unable to access server using real android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, httpurlconnection

I'm having trouble accessing my server (WAMP) using my real android device. I have an app that downloads the data and parsing it to my listview. In the emulator everything is working fine using "10.0.2.2" I tried 10.0.2.2:80, 10.0.2.2(without port #), (my laptop's ip) 192.168.254.103:80 and 192.168.254.103 (without port #) in my url. My WAMP is online and I even tried turning off firewall. Is there something missing?

UPDATE

I tried browsing via my phone's browser the ip address of my laptop and it says "FORBIDDEN". i tried configuring the httpd.conf of apache based on what I've researched but still can't access the server. please help.

Comment: I tried browsing via my phone's browser the ip address of my laptop and it says "FORBIDDEN". i tried configuring the httpd.conf of apache based on what I've researched but still can't access the server. please help.

Comment: For the Forbidden error, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405288/5180017) StackOverflow thread or [this](https://www.digifloor.com/simple-steps-fix-403-forbidden-errors-wamp-server-28) post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off Firewall -
2. Give permission to "WAMP folder" by using Folder
   sharing options - Basically access to "All" for read, write