# You don't have permission to access check.php on this server

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache

I am trying to connect Android Application with WAMP server for accessing DB content. After running the code in the response it is prompting as; I have put WAMP online, having `Apache version 2.4.18`. Also, WAMP icon is green. I also added `Require all granted` in all `.conf` files but still it is not working.

```
V/REGISTERActivity: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
                    <html><head>
                    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
                    </head><body>
                    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
                    <p>You don't have permission to access /check.php
                    on this server.<br />
                    </p>
                    <hr>
                    <address>Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 Server at 192.168.11.100 Port 80</address>
                    </body></html>
```

**phpmyadmin.conf**

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.5.1/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted


# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

**phpsysinfo**

```
Alias /phpsysinfo "c:/wamp64/apps/phpsysinfo3.2.5/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpsysinfo3.2.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**adminer.conf**

```
Alias /adminer "c:/wamp64/apps/adminer4.2.4/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/adminer4.2.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Code**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.11.100/check.php";
    private OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    EditText userNameTextEdit, passwordTextEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //
        userNameTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usenameText);
        passwordTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // handle login
                String username = userNameTextEdit.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordTextEdit.getText().toString();
                registerUser(username, password);
            }
        });
    }

    public void registerUser(String username, String password) {
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("username", username)
                .add("password", password)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL).post(body).build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Registration Error" + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    String resp = response.body().string();
                    Log.v("REGISTERActivity", resp);
//                    userNameTextEdit.setText(resp);
                    System.out.println(resp);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Log.e(TAG_REGISTER, "Exception caught: ", e);
                    System.out.println("Exception caught" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I also tried by adding `Alow from ::1` in phpmyadmin.conf file. But still not working. Any there?

Answer (score 0):

Your wamp server does not allow to request. You need to configure your server. check out following answer. it might help you.
[WAMP error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

Comment: I already applied the solution given in the link you have suggested. But did not work.