# WAMP - Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I'm trying to access my WAMP webserver (3.1.4) over the internet, and I am receiving permission errors even after going through every answered question on the topic on stack exchange.

WAMP is set to "online" and is green. I can access my server on my host computer and see everyone of my web pages fine. I can even view and navigate the website fine using the domain name, so that isn't the issue.

My firewall has inbound connection on the listening port open, and my router has port forwarding enabled for the port as well.

I have granted all permissions in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# Virtual Hosts
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/example"

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php)?$ [OR]
        RewriteCond $1 \.(gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js)$ [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [S=1]
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END wordpress

    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/example/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have granted all permissions in httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    AllowOverride all

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have granted all permissions in phpmyadmin.conf:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.3/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.8.3/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require all granted
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Allow from ::1
    </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

I have granted all permissions in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   example.com
::1 example.com
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to show an additional setting in httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s

Comment: @Nisha, thanks for the suggestion. I have actually implemented all of those changes in my code, and I have noted in my question ever file that has been changed which are all a product of that question.

Comment: Do you have access from another device presiding within the same LAN?

Comment: @arueckauer, I do not. I have not even attempted to try over LAN, as all my permissions are set to allow all so I would be going backwards in terms of granting access. It could possibly work over LAN, but that would require me to set up my server to operate over LAN and change all my permissions to be more restrictive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the domain name was not redirecting to my host, but to the DNS of the site where I purchased the domain. The permissions I set were all right, so it was an alternative solution that I wasn't familiar with.