# Error WAMP: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/7.4.26 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: php, apache, permissions, wamp, wampserver

**Summarize the problem:**
**I TRY ALL FIXED INSTRUCTION**

I need the ability to run python file, for this i do all what in [this instruction](https://overcoder.net/q/370756/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-python-%D1%81-wampserver#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D1%8B%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%2B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20python%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20localhost%20(wampserver%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%D0%B4.)%3A)

I all finished, start index.py file(localhost/index.py)

And me write this problem

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/7.4.26 Server at localhost Port 80
```

**Describe what you`ve tried**

1. I try fixed this problem with [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366976/wamp-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-phpmyadmin-on-this-s)

   But change in phpmyadmin not help me, below will be the code file phpmyadmin.conf
2. I try change *Require local* on *Require all granted*. In *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\conf\httpd.conf*, below will be the code
3. I try add value in file *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf*, bellow cod

**Show some code**

phpmyadmin4.9.7.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin4.9.7 "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.9.7/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.9.7/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

phpmyadmin.conf

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin5.1.1/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin5.1.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">

    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
    
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf (not all code)

```
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#   Don't modify this line - Instead modify Require of VirtualHost in httpd-vhost.conf
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: What possible use is your `phpMyAdmin` config files

Comment: I think with your skill level, you would be better to use XAMPP as that comes with Python already installed if I remember correctly

Comment: But even then, if you change something in an Apache or any config file. Please read up on what it does before you blindly mess the config up

Comment: So, okay. Me need XAMPP or anything easier
Thanks for tips!